# XCode: iOS5 localization script - Exit code 1

Tags: xcode, ios5, localization, storyboard

i'm using the popular pythonscript ( http://code.google.com/p/edim-mobile/source/browse/trunk/ios/IncrementalLocalization/localize.py ) to localize my storyboards in ios5.

I did only some changes in storyboard and got this error:

> Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning
>   message and any useful information you can provide.  
>      com.apple.ibtool.errors
>                        description          The strings
>   file "MainStoryboard.strings" could not be applied.
>             recovery-suggestion          Missing object referenced
>   from oid-keyed mapping. Object ID ztT-UO-myJ
>             underlying-errors            
>                 
>                     description
>                     The strings file "MainStoryboard.strings" could not be applied.
>                     recovery-suggestion
>                     Missing object referenced from oid-keyed mapping. Object ID ztT-UO-myJ
>                                              Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./localize.py", line 105, in 
>       raise Exception("\n" + errorDescription) Exception:
>
> *** Error while creating the 'Project/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard' file***
>
> *** Error while creating the 'Project/es.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard' file***
>
> *** Error while creating the 'Project/fr.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard' file***
>
> *** Error while creating the 'Project/it.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard' file***
>
> Showing first 200 notices only Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

I can't find a solution..

Maik

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interface Builder could not open the document ".xib" because it does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968715/interface-builder-could-not-open-the-document-xib-because-it-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you made the changes to the storyboard, you removed an Interface Builder object from the storyboard with the ID *ztT-UO-myJ*. Hence the error message shown.

Try to search for that ID in MainStoryboard.strings file and remove the whole line. After that try again to run the script.

Comment: @maik639 try to look for invalid IB outlet in your storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

If ibtool fails with

> Interface Builder could not open the document NAME.storyboard because
>   it does not exist

Execute this in terminal:

```
killall -9 ibtoold
```

Found at:
http://oleb.net/blog/2013/02/automating-strings-extraction-from-storyboards-for-localization/

P.S. The link contains a better script. https://github.com/ole/Storyboard-Strings-Extraction

P.S. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19997562/991816) has links to articles about may be even better [scripts](https://github.com/AppliedIS/iOSL10n)